# How to convert multiple .caf audio files to .wav?

Tags: macos, audio, file-conversion

I have downloaded an iPad app called LaunchPad in which you put sounds into buttons aligned in squares so they can be easily played. The problem is that this LaunchPad app only accepts .wav audio files and all my audio effects are in the .caf format and they are like a hundred sounds. Is there a program to convert multiple files (a whole folder of files) into another format?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [afconvert](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/afconvert.1.html):

```
afconvert sound.caf sound.wav
```

This can be run on an entire folder using find:

```
find /path/to/folder/ -name "*.caf" -exec afconvert {} {}.wav \;
```

Comment: Not working for me. Tells me `No output file or data format specified.`.

Answer (score 5):

You can use ffmpeg ([binary](http://ffmpegmac.net) or install with Homebrew):

```
ffmpeg -i sound.caf sound.wav
```

This can be run on an entire folder using find:

```
find /path/to/folder/ -name "*.caf" -exec ffmpeg -i {} {}.wav \;
```