# How to convert .wav to .mp3 and maintain iTunes presence?

Tags: itunes, file-conversion, encoding, mp3, audio

I have a bunch of .wav files (from synced CDs) that I would like to convert to .mp3 files in order to save space. I found [this link](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/173336/how-to-convert-multiple-caf-audio-files-to-wav) which works to batch convert .wav to .mp3, but unfortunately iTunes does not automagically recognize the new .mp3 files.

I would like to know if there is a way to batch convert .wav files to .mp3 files and have iTunes maintain its metadata of those files. (Of course, this all could have been prevented by syncing the CDs as .mp3s in the first place. Oops.)

[FLAC to iTunes](https://github.com/christopher-b/flac-to-itunes) also seems like it might be useful, but I'm dealing with .wav files and would need to convert them all to FLAC files before using this tool, and I'm not sure how to do that without losing metadata.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Select the songs you want to convert
- Use the option under File > Convert > Create MP3 Version

This option is disabled if you are actively syncing a CD.

Answer (score -1):

There is a 3rd party, free app named [Adapter](https://macroplant.com/adapter) that converts image, audio, and video files. It runs in batch mode and worked fine for images. Read about it at the link I provided.

Comment: why was this downvoted?  Adapter is a great free app.